# SSH keeps getting stuck during connection

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have a little problem. My ssh keeps hanging, I cant connect to anything. This is the output I get with `ssh -T git@github.com`

```
root@luk164:~# ssh -vvv -T git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-1, OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.118.4] port 22.
```

After that it is stuck forever until I terminate it. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: Drop the `-T` switch.

Comment: Thanks but that was not the problem, it was my network blocking ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found out that the problem was in the network, it was blocking any and all ssh connections in and out. I am still surprised that ssh could not detect that and instead tried to connect forever, not even timing out.

Comment: How did you identify whether the `ssh` connection was being blocked by your network or not? I am also got stuck with `ssh` showing connecting forever on several WiFi networks.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you but it was stated in our university website, so it is probably of no use to you.

Comment: Ow - never mind, my issue was solved by restarting my mac. Probably some network cache/device was misbehaving.